# Suppress iOS Console Output "Unloading xxx unused Assets..."

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, logging, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to suppress console output in iPhone player when a new scene is loaded using [Application.LoadLevelAdditiveAsync](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAdditiveAsync.html) or similar methods?

```
Unloading 7 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0 / Dirty serialized files: 0)  
Unloading 185 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 3468. Operation took 377.272217 ms.
System memory in use: 6.7 MB.
```

Yes it might not be the most important thing on earth but it's somewhat annoying when looking for relevant error messages within noisy output.